# Can't understand the mapping inside mapping

Tags: solidity, blockchain, remix, tokens, hardhat

I'm writing the BEP20 token contract. I'm taking help from [here](https://blog.logrocket.com/how-to-create-deploy-bep-20-token-binance-smart-chain/), as it is my first time interaction with the standard. First at first, they have set the mapping inside mapping.

```
mapping(address => mapping(address => uint256)) public allowance;
```

**I can't understand the concept of allowance and why they set it like this,**

secondly, in `approve()` and `transferFrom()` they are utilizing the allowance like this.

allowance[_from][msg.sender]... in `transferFrom()` and
allowance[msg.sender][_spender]... in `approve()`.

**Is this the right way to access mapping inside mapping, or we do it like this?
allowance[something][something] neglegting '' and what is the purpose of ''.**

Anyone up there to make my concept clear? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say that you have user A and B. User A owns 10000 tokens, but user B owns none. User A can of course transfer its tokens, but he would also like user B to be able to transfer his tokens on his behalf. This is where the concept of allowance come in.

By calling the `approve()` function, user A authorizes user B to transfer his tokens on his behalf, up to the amount of tokens that was approved. To do so, user B would use the `transferFrom()` function.

The allowance is how many tokens B can transfer on behalf of user A (so, the initial approve amount minus any transfer made by user B for user A tokens).

As for the double mapping, the contract has to keep track of potentially multiple approvals made by user A for different spenders addresses (say, user B and user C). The outer mapping key would be user A, whereas the inner mapping key would be user B and the value would be the amount of tokens approved by user A to user B.

```
mapping(USER_A_ADDRESS => mapping(USER_B_ADDRESS => AMOUNT_APPROVED)) public allowance;
```

When accessing the mapping in the `approve()` function, `msg.sender` is user A (user A is making the approval in favor of user B). In `transferFrom()`, `msg.sender` is user B (user B is making a transfer of user A tokens).

I strongly suggest that you use [OpenZeppelin contracts](https://docs.openzeppelin.com/contracts/4.x/erc20).

Comment: Thank you so much! And I'll add openzeppelin contracts, thanks.

Comment: Can you tell me how would I access this mapping while testing the smartcontract?
normally if it is traditional mapping I'm doing it like bep20.balanceOf(spender.address); in javascript

Comment: From within your contract, you would access it with allowance[userA][userB]. From a different contract, you would make a call to the contract with bep20.allowance(userA, userB)

Comment: If you want to make a call from javascript with web3js, look up other answers on how to make calls to contract (or in the web3js doc). You want to call the allowance function.